# Создать ArrayList<Integer> с фиксированной длиной Java

Tags: java, массивы, list, динамические-массивы, arraylist

У меня возникла проблема. Когда я создаю `ArrayList`, используя конструктор, где указывается длина, размер `ArrayList` **всегда равен нулю**.

```
ArrayList<Integer> d = new ArrayList<>(si + 1);
```

.

```
Log.d("e", String.valueOf(d.size()));
```

Вывод:

```
0
```

.

```
Log.d("e", String.valueOf(si + 1));
```

Вывод:

```
1
```

Подскажите, как правильно создать такой массив.

Весь метод:

```
    String[] sp = str.split(":");
    int s = Integer.parseInt(sp[0]);
    int f = Integer.parseInt(sp[1]);
    boolean j = Boolean.parseBoolean(sp[2]);
    if(j){
        int si = Integer.parseInt(sp[3]);
        ArrayList<Integer> d = new ArrayList<>(si + 1);
        for(int i = 0; i < si; i++){
            d.set(i, Integer.parseInt(sp[i + 4]));
        }
        return new Move(s, f, d);
    }
    return new Move(s, f);
```

Comment: Покажите полный код

Comment: А нельзя использовать просто массив?
А если нужны методы List, можно воспользоваться
Arrays.stream(ints).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()); 

Вообще сам по себе ArrayList это динамический массив, зачем вам урезать длину?

Comment: Я могу заполнить его с помощью метода Add, но я знаю его длину, и поэтому решил сразу указать.

Comment: Таким образом Вы выделяете память под будущий список. Но пока Вы туда ничего не добавите, он естественно будет пустым. Но при добавлении не будет перераспределяться память. Так что правильно создаёте:)

Comment: Вместо `d.set(i, Integer.parseInt(sp[i + 4]));` следует сделать так `d.add(Integer.parseInt(sp[i + 4]));` Потому, что индекс выходит за границы массива сразу же. 
И не `new ArrayList<>(si + 1);`, а `new ArrayList<>(si);` Зачем резервировать на единицу больше, чем нужно?

Comment: Sergey, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Когда я создаю `ArrayList`, используя конструктор, где указывается длина, размер `ArrayList` **всегда равен нулю**.*

В конструкторе [`ArrayList(int initialCapacity)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-) задаётся **НЕ размер**, а **ёмкость** создаваемого списка, чтобы слегка оптимизировать заполнение списка заранее известным количеством элементов.  Сам же список создаётся пустым:

> `public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)`
> Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.

---

> Создать ArrayList с фиксированной длиной

`ArrayList` - по определению является реализацией интерфейса `List` на базе расширяемого массива:

> Resizable-array implementation of the `List` interface.

Если задача состоит в том, чтобы создать список *заданной длины*, в который нельзя будет добавлять элементы, можно использовать метод [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-), для создания списка фиксированной длины, но для этого потребуется преобразовать массив строк в массив `Integer` при помощи Stream API, в частности получив поток "строк", начиная с нужного индекса при помощи [`Arrays.stream(T[] arr, int from, int to)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-int-int-):

```java
List<Integer> d = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.stream(sp, 4, 4 + si)
          .map(Integer::parseInt)
          .toArray(Integer[]::new)
);
```

Или же можно воспользоваться вариантами коллекторов `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()` (Java 10+) или `Stream.toList` (Java 16+) или `Collectors.collectingAndThen` + `Collections.unmodifiableList` (Java 8+):

```java
List<Integer> java10 = Arrays.stream(sp, 4, 4 + si)
          .map(Integer::parseInt)
          .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());

List<Integer> java16 = Arrays.stream(sp, 4, 4 + si)
          .map(Integer::parseInt)
          .toList();

List<Integer> java8 = Arrays.stream(sp, 4, 4 + si)
          .map(Integer::parseInt)
          .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
              Collectors.toList(), Collections::unmodifiableList
          ));
```